# Bootstrap NavBar Too Many Elements

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I am working on a project that has dynamic elements in the menu. The issue I am running into is that sometime there is a very large number of items in the menu. When this happens the navbar will expand down and show the elements.The issue with this is that I need the navbar to stay the same height.

Ideally I would want the navbar to take the elements that don't fit and put them into a dropdown or otherwise take care of them. Is this possible with bootstrap?

Comment: So to clarify, you want the items to still be on the navbar while the overflowing items to be contained in a dropdown menu? I don't think it's possible only using bootstrap. you might need javascript/jQuery to move the elements that's overflowing into the dropdown menu.

Comment: It really doesn't even need to be fancy. I just don't know how many elements will end up in the navbar and when you have to many the navbar just starts to grow it's height. I really just want a way to keep the navbar from expanding it's height while still allowing users to get to the options.